# unable to iterate through lists and extract data

Tags: python

I am having some trouble with my python script. I want to be able to grab the values from a text file, place them inside a list and the extract the numbers that meet and fail the criteria. My problem is happening when I split and extract the data from the text file. I am able to iterate through the list, but when it comes to organizing the data, I am not seeing the proper data.I want to be able to place the numbers that are greater than y in a list and the numbers that are less than Y in another list. The text file that I am passing contains floats this file has 8 lines.

```
def openTextFileAndRead(x):
    > x = sys.argv[1]
    organized_high = []
    organized_low = []
    index = 0
    y = float(109.0)
    with open(x, 'r') as f:
        unorganizedFloatList = []
        for lines in f:
            unorganizedFloatList.append(lines.rstrip().split(","))
            lenghOfList = len(unorganizedFloatList)
        for numbers in unorganizedFloatList:
            index += 1
            if numbers >= y:
                print ("printing the numbers that meet the high number requirements\n")
                organized_high.append(numbers)
                print organized_high
                if index == lenghOfList:
                    break
            else:
                print('printing numbers that didnt meet the high requirements')
                organized_low.append(numbers)
                print organized_low
```

output

```
[['12.3']]
printing the numbers that meet the high number requirements

[['12.3'], ['124.5']]
printing the numbers that meet the high number requirements

[['12.3'], ['124.5'], ['54.3']]
printing the numbers that meet the high number requirements

[['12.3'], ['124.5'], ['54.3'], ['53.2']]
printing the numbers that meet the high number requirements

[['12.3'], ['124.5'], ['54.3'], ['53.2'], ['3.2']]
printing the numbers that meet the high number requirements

[['12.3'], ['124.5'], ['54.3'], ['53.2'], ['3.2'], ['8.0']]
```

Comment: using python 2.7

Comment: Sample text file and expected output, please.

Comment: `lines.rstrip().split(",")` this returns a string list which you add to your list. Later on you compare it by a float which would raise `TypeError`. Use e.g. `unorganizedFloatList.append(float(lines.rstrip().split(",")[0]))`.

Comment: >12.3
>124.5
>54.2
>53.2
>3.2
>9.0

Answer (score 1):

```
for lines in f:
    unorganizedFloatList.append(lines.rstrip().split(","))
    lenghOfList = len(unorganizedFloatList)
```

There's no point here in calculating the length of the list in each iteration. You probably want to calculate the length after you filled the list:

```
for lines in f:
    unorganizedFloatList.append(lines.rstrip().split(","))
lenghOfList = len(unorganizedFloatList)
```

Also, about this line:

```
unorganizedFloatList.append(lines.rstrip().split(","))
```

Split returns a list. So you are appending lists to a list and that's the reason why your prints show lists of lists. For what i see your splits are always returning just 1 value, so to have a flat list you probably want:

```
unorganizedFloatList.append(lines.rstrip().split(",")[0])
```

This way you are always getting the first element of the split and appending that to your list will give you a flat list of strings. Is this why you say you are not seeing "proper data"?

And you don't need to keep track of indexes here:

```
for numbers in unorganizedFloatList:
        index += 1
        if numbers >= y:
            print ("printing the numbers that meet the high number requirements\n")
            organized_high.append(numbers)
            print organized_high
            if index == lenghOfList:
                break
```

This for cicle will exit before your index equals the lenght of the list. You are already using a for cicle to iterate through all the elements, you don't need indexes for that.

Comment: Thanks I will review your comments Andre!